# Why does the browser display question marks from MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, character-encoding

So the language I use is Java, with JSP-s and Servlets I try to give html what it should print but it just prints question marks. My data is in MySQL. I tried to change everything to UTF-8 including tomcats, xml and html document's, JSP's and MySQL workbench's character encodings, but it didn't help. And one important notation - **the `System.out.println(...);` function correctly prints the text in the console**(as expected). Please help.

Comment: And the browser also uses UTF-8?

Comment: One question mark per string?  Or many?  Two different cases.

Comment: How did you set Workbench's character encoding?

Comment: I didn't change it sorry, it was initially utf-8_general_ci

Answer (score 1):

- The bytes in the client must be utf8-encoded.
- The connection must establish that fact.  For servelets  `resource.setContentType ("text/html;charset=utf-8");`.
- The tables/columns must be `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or `utf8mb4`).
- The output must declare utf8.  For JSP:  `<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>`

For multiple question marks, the usual flaw is in the table definition.  Alternately, the source bytes and the connection could be at fault.

To check what is in the table, please provide the output from this for some non-English character(s):

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...
```

Comment: The output of the Select col. hex(col) from... was 'D588D59ED5BE20D5A720D5A3D680D5A5D5AC203C3CD580D5A1D680D5A9D5A1D5A3D5B8D5B2D5AB20D5B3D5A1D5B4D683D5B8D680D5A4D5B6D5A5D680D5A83E3E3A' for 1 of the entries. What can I assume now?

Comment: All 4 points you mentioned, were done with some minor differencies, recource.contentType() does it mean response.contentType()? Also utf-8_general_ci is used in MySQL workbench.

Comment: That looks like Armenian characters encoded in utf8.  So, the data is stored 'correctly'.  So, need to look at the output side.  If you can get hex from Java, see if it also looks like `D5xx`.  And look at the html output to see if it says `charset=UTF-8`, probably in a `meta` tag near the beginning.